# How can I prove that the eigenvalues of $TS$ are all nonnegative if $T$ and $S$ are positive operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let  $V$ be a finite dim. real/ complex inner product space, and $T \in L(V)$ and $S \in L(V)$ we let be positive operators, how can I prove that the 
eigenvalues of $TS$ are all nonnegative?

My approach so far is to work with the definition of a positive operator:

$T \in L(V)$ is called **positive** if $T$ is self-adjoint and  $\geq$ $0$.

However, I am not sure where I am supposed to introduce the notion of a self-adjoint operator. Perhaps I don't need it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $TS$ and $T^{1/2} S T^{1/2}$ have the same eigenvalues.